# Ext.data.Store proxy does not parse nested JSON and its Models

Tags: json, extjs, extjs-stores

I'm just trying to parse a nested JSON in a Model that I've created. I've created three models  (Detalhe, Propriedade and Assinatura) for each JSON node. The store proxy isn't parsing the data for Detalhe's model.

I also tryed to put the "mapping" property on hasMany attribute, with the same name of a node. It didn't work. Ext.Template also can't read store data and fill the Viewer.

Any suggestions?

Here is my JSON:

```
{
   "details": {
      "customProperties": [
         {
            "chave": "Data de Criação",
            "valor": "30/10/2013"
         },
         {
            "chave": "Nome",
            "valor": "Blah Stuff"
         }
      ],
      "signatures": [
         {
            "nome": "Data de Criação",
            "data": "30/10/2013"
         },
         {
            "nome": "Nome do Cliente",
            "data": "John Doe"
         }
      ]
   },
   "success": true
}
```

And the parsing code:

```
Ext.define('Propriedade', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            fields: ['chave', 'valor'],
            belongsTo: 'Detalhe'
        });

        Ext.define('Assinatura', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            fields: ['nome', 'data'],
            belongsTo: 'Detalhe'
        });

        Ext.define('Detalhe', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            hasMany: [
                {model: 'Propriedade', name: 'customProperties'},
                {model: 'Assinatura', name: 'signatures'}
            ]
        });

        var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            id: 'customPropertiesStore',
            model: 'Detalhe',
            autoLoad: false,
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'info.json',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'details',
                    successProperty: 'success'
                }
            }
        });

        var docId = "some id"; 
        var folders = "some folder";

        store.load({
            params: {docId: docId, folders: folders}
        });

        var tpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
            '<tpl for="customProperties">',
                '<div class="customPropertyItem">',
                    '<span><label>{chave}</label>: {valor}</span>',
                '</div>',
            '</tpl>',
            '<tpl for="signatures">',
                '<div class="signatureItem">',
                    '<span><label>{nome}</label>: {data}</span>',
                '</div>',
            '</tpl>'
            );

        var viewer = Ext.create('Ext.view.View', {
            store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('customPropertiesStore'),
            tpl: tpl,
            itemSelector: 'customPropertyItem',
            emptyText: 'Nothing found.'
        });
```

Comment: I don't know if you can edit the server side script. This is where I would start to receive a cleaner json.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't.